# Why I'm getting time limit exceeded for this code in hackerearth, little shino and common factors problem in python

Tags: python

I'm getting time limit exceeded for this code in hackerearth, 'little shino and common factors' problem in python, can someone help me with the problem

```
        a,b = map(int,input().split())
        n = 0
        for i in range(1,min(a,b)+1):
            if a%i==b%i==0 :
                n+=1
        print (n)
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Remember that there are no factors larger than k/2.  Indeed, you can count up to sqrt(k) and multiply by 2.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting TLE because the `min(a, b)` is returning a number greater than 10<sup>6</sup>. 
Generally speaking, for a given coding question if there is a time limit of 1 second and your code run for more than 10<sup>6</sup> times, you will get TLE (time limit exceeded). You can read more about it from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overcome-time-limit-exceedtle/).

Comment: That website requires a login. I wish it wasn't the first or second result in Google so much.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can skip login if you wish. And the first or second search results are result of google's search algorithm, I don't understand the problem there

Comment: You must be logged into the website. I don't see your point. Of course, every search result from Google is a result of Google's search algorithm. My point is I'd prefer top results not to force a login.